# Migrating from 1.51.1 to 1.56.1 results in undefined reference

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

we've been using gRPC v1.51.1 without issue for some time and I've just tried to update to a later version and am having some issues.  I'm on Centos7 and using GCC v9.3.0p6 in an HPC chamber so don't have much ability to change this.

I'm using CMake to generate the protobuf outputs and generate a shared library which I then pass to my main application.

The first issue I had was that a load more libraries were needed to compile on 1.56.1 that weren't needed on 1.51.1.  I assume that might just be due to a refactoring of sources?

The second issue I'm seeing is an undefined reference:

`` undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::thread_cache_' ``

Searching libprotobuf.so for similar symbols gives me this:

`/projects/common/tools/grpc/v1.56.1/lib64/libprotobuf.so:00000000001d9a68 T google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::thread_cache() /projects/common/tools/grpc/v1.56.1/lib64/libprotobuf.so:0000000000000000 d google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::thread_cache()::thread_cache`

What am I doing wrong?

I had a quick Google and looked for similar issues but have come up blank.  Reverting to using the older version of gRPC sees the issue disappear.

I've recompiled the latter version making sure I was using exactly the same GCC version in case I messed up but no change.

The libs I'm using are:

```
-LDFLAGS "-L$(GRPC_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -L$(GRPC_INSTALL_PATH)/lib64"
-LDFLAGS "-lgrpc -lgrpc++ -lgpr -labsl_synchronization -lprotobuf -lgrpc++_reflection"
-LDFLAGS "-labsl_log_internal_message -labsl_log_internal_check_op -labsl_cord -labsl_cordz_info -labsl_cordz_functions"
```

My CMakeLists.txt for the protobuf generation looks like:

```
project(genesee_protobuf LANGUAGES CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

find_package(protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

set(PROTO_FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/genesee_protobuf/discovery/discovery.proto
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/genesee_protobuf/backdoor_memory_interface/backdoor_memory_interface.proto
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/genesee_protobuf/trace/trace.proto
)

set(PROTO_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
set(PROTO_IMPORT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

add_library(genesee_protobuf ${PROTO_FILES})
target_link_libraries(genesee_protobuf PUBLIC protobuf::libprotobuf gRPC::grpc gRPC::grpc++)
target_include_directories(genesee_protobuf PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}>")

#
# Compile protobuf and grpc files in genesee_protobuf target to cpp
#
get_target_property(grpc_cpp_plugin_location gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin LOCATION)

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET genesee_protobuf
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIR}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR ${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}
    LANGUAGE cpp)

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET genesee_protobuf
    LANGUAGE grpc
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIR}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR ${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc
    PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}")
```

Comment: You don't seem to run the updated `protoc` with your proto files.

Comment: So after going through a bunch of releases of gRPC, it seems the issue I'm hitting comes in at v1.55.0 which also seems to be when protobuf was bumped to 22.x.

Comment: @273K - can you expand on what you think the issue is?  I'm using the bundled gRPC dependencies installed alongside.  Nothing on my system.